# Error Message on Ubuntu Software Center "There isn't a software package called "corebreach" in your current software sources."

Tags: games

When I open the Ubuntu Software Center and I try to install the game CoreBreach by clicking on the Ubuntu Software Center on-top banner I get the message: "There isn't a software package called "corebreach" in your current software sources."

This is how my software sources screen look like:

Answer (score 0):

get the game here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/oneiric/?q=corebreach
[image]

Comment: Good afternoon, I have Oneiric installed on my computer and I can see corebreach on the Web based Ubuntu Software Center. But when I hit install it pops up the Ubuntu Software Center with the same error message.

Comment: If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: I can purchase it on Desura or on Gameolith but I would like to purchase everything on Ubuntu Software Center for a better control.