# Software Center PDF Studio 7 link not working

Tags: software-center, package-management, software-sources

[image: Software Center Home]

When I open the Software Center I see this big banner advertisement for PDF Studio 7. I click it, and I get the error 'Not found' 'There isn't a software package called "pdfstudio7" in your current software sources'.

[image: Not Found error]

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=There%20isn%27t%20a%20software%20package%20called%20%22pdfstudio%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gl=uk#hl=en&gs_nf=1&pq=there%20isn%27t%20a%20software%20package%20called%20%22pdfstudio%22&cp=83&gs_id=64&xhr=t&q=There%20isn%27t%20a%20software%20package%20called%20%22pdfstudio7%22%20in%20your%20current%20software%20sources&pf=p&client=ubuntu&hs=fNa&channel=fs&gl=uk&sclient=psy-ab&oq=There%20isn%27t%20a%20software%20package%20called%20%22pdfstudio7%22%20in%20your%20current%20software%20sources&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=cd67df33bd91fd3c&biw=1101&bih=851) for that error message gives zero results. A [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108603/error-message-on-ubuntu-software-center-there-isnt-a-software-package-called) here on Ask Ubuntu recommends looking for it online as a workaround.

The other two ads for 'Steel Storm' and 'Uplink' work as expected, bringing me to the details page for each application.

Is this just a bug report to be filed or am I missing something basic here?

Edit: Bug report [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/949816)

Comment: I get the same over here. I believe that it's a typo behind the advertisement and that the package should be 'pdfstudio' (exists) and not 'pdfstudio7'.

Comment: @yossile this should be an answer.

Comment: Anyone know how to check and see if this typo theory is correct? I will flag this as off topic/bug report if I can confirm the issue.

Comment: This is a redirect bug in the Software Center client of which we're waiting for an SRU to be released. The SRU is in -proposed currently. The fix is to clear out your ~/.cache/software-center/scaclient directory (close software center, move scaclient out, restart software center)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update your packages with `sudo apt-get update` prior to install.

I am not sure but I think the banner feed has nothing to do with the status of your lists so there is a chance you see software in the banner that has not been updated to your packages list.

If that does not work change the server from what your have at the moment to *main server* and try to update again.

If updating your lists and changing server did not work you should definitely report this as a bug.

Comment: Right, tried both suggestions and still have the same issue. That's a bug, so I'll flag the question for closure as off-topic. Thanks for the help.